# change current day in full calendar day view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to change date of view like if I select 25/12/2019 then it should show  December 25, 2019 as a heading. How can I do that?
[image]

FYI: I'm using react Full-calendar plugin

```
<FullCalendar
  defaultView="timeGridDay"
  header={{
    left: "prev,next today",
    center: "title"
  }}
  plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
  weekends={this.state.calendarWeekends}
  events={this.state.calendarEvents}
  dateClick={this.handleDateClick}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [titleFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting)

use moment Plugin

```
import momentPlugin from '@fullcalendar/moment';

<FullCalendar
  defaultView="timeGridDay"
  header={{
    left: "prev,next today",
    center: "title"
  }}
  plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
  weekends={this.state.calendarWeekends}
  events={this.state.calendarEvents}
  dateClick={this.handleDateClick}
  titleFormat='MMMM D, YYYY'
/>
```

Comment: THis is producing an error, not getting the correct output.

Comment: @HarshPatel i have update my coding. please check if any problem let me know.

Comment: Yes, the same thing I did,`{
        month: 8,
        year: 2019,
        day: 1
      }` but it is not working due to some plugin error

Comment: @HarshPatel l I have updated my coding. please check.

Comment: More likely the object (from your original version) should simply have an extra bracket - like the "header" option does. E.g. `titleFormat={{
        month: 'long',
        year: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric'
      }}`. This seems to be syntax which is specific to the Angular plugin

Comment: Ps. @HarshPatel if you ever get an error you should mention what it says, in case we can fix it. Saying there is "some error" does not allow people to help you resolve it

Comment: @HarshPatel no problem...so did my suggested change to the titleFormat work for you, or not?

Comment: @ADyson I'm already providing double bracket and Now I removed headers as of now.

Comment: @MohammadAliRony I'll try later this moment code and let you know, thank you for the help.